# Reference variable shows undefind behaviour after the next line of program execution

Tags: c++

Below is the piece of code which shows different output for same operation. Why I am getting different values in the below `cout`s? Please share your thoughts on this.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int const& f(int i=9, int j=99, int=999) {
    return i;
}

int main() {
    const int &k = f();
    //cout<<" \n hello \n"; //If I enable this cout thenn all the below will only print some junk values(even if I remove the const!!).
    cout<<"\n"<<k<<" "<<k<<" "<<k;  //prints "9 9 9"
    cout<<"\n\n"<<k<<" "<<k<<" "<<k<<"\n";  //prints "134520896 134520896 134520896", some garbage value. why is it so?
    cout<<"\n\n"<<k<<" "<<k<<" "<<k<<"\n\n";    //prints "134520896 134520896 134520896", some garbage value. why is it so?
}
```

If the lifetime of `i` is limited to the scope of the function call then why its printing correctly three times at line 13 and why its not when I uncomment line 12?

Please share your thoughts on this with a detailed explanation would be helpful.

Comment: Can you take out the line numbers so we can easily run it on our machines?

Comment: Because undefined behavior means _anything_ can happen including executing as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this statement

```
const int &k = f();
```

reference returned by functtion f is invalid because the life of local variable i was finished after exiting the function.

So the both reference that is the reference returned by the function and the reference named k are invalid.

So the program has undefined behaviour.

However you could make your program well-formed if you would redefine the function the following way

```
int f( int i=9, int j=99, int=999 ) 
{
   return i;
}
```

In this case statement

```
const int &k = f();
```

would be valid and the temporary object would be alive while the reference is alive.

Answer (score 5):

This is undefined behaviour, so anything could happen. As you say, the lifetime of `i` is limited to the function's scope, so the reference is not to a valid object.

Probably, the stack memory formerly occupied by `i` isn't overwritten until the next function call, to `operator<<`. If the compiler evaluates all the arguments in the first line before the first function call, then they will still have the value left behind by the function. Afterwards, the memory has been overwritten, so you see garbage.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case of : [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 1):

Well, what you're returning is a constant reference to an integer. Problem is, that reference refers to an object that might not be valid anymore. i is local to `f()`, and when that function ends, the computer is free to do anything it wants with the memory location that i used to reside in.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you call

```
const int &k = f();
```

compiler transforms it to

```
const int &k = f(int i=9, int j=99, int=999);
```

in asm it will be something like this

```
push 9
push 99
push 999
push some registers
call f
pop some registers
pop //your 999 was here
pop //your 99 was here
pop //your 9 was here
```

So in k you receive an address in stack. It contained 9 earlier but now 9 is already popped. So anything could be here. It is why you receive garbage.

Comment: I have studied ASM 10 years ago and never used it. But I am pretty sure about push/pop logic.

Comment: @Avt A lot depends on the architecture; I doubt any compiler would emit exactly that sequence.  On the rare machines where arguments are passed on the stack (32 bit Intel, but is there any other today?), the compiler would probably just fix-up the stack pointer, rather than do any `pop`; in some cases, it might just allocate the parameters as if they were local variables at the right address (and so avoid the `push` as well).  And of course, on most machines (including 64 bit AMD), the compiler will just put the values into registers.

Comment: I have wrote "something like this" :) It could be veeery different "something".

Comment: @Avt You can BTW easily check which asm is really generated using e.g. `-S` option of GCC ...